# facebook page access token for 'editor' role

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Is it possible to get facebook PAGE access_token with USER access_token if the user is not the owner of the page, but has 'editor' role (for example)?

If yes, then how.

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#permissions) is described how to do that, but you must have ADMIN role.

I'm using Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is specifically addressed in the documentation.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens#roles)

> ...
>   Your app will need to have the Admin role and permissions.
>   ...
>   As you're building your page-related app, you need the Admin permissions for a Page, contact a current Admin of that page and they can add you.

The answer is no. You can not access the Graph API or create content on behalf of a page without `admin` permissions.